# afterTextChanged automatically triggered when switching orientation of the device

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, listener

**SOLVED**

I have solved the error. It was not related to the original question but to debugging my code.I simply had some problems with some variables.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**
I have a `EditText` which has attached a `listener` to trigger some methods when the the value has changed (it works)

**Activity**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initUI();
    }

 private void initUI() {
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_view);

   editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable query) {
            if (!query.toString().isEmpty())
               // Trigger methods
            else
                myFragment.emptyListView();
        }
    });
}
```

**Fragment**

```
private void emptyListView() {
     String[] aux = new String[names.size()];
     names.toArray(aux);
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(m_activity, R.layout.row, aux);
     if (m_activity.findViewById(R.id.listView) != null) {
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }
}
```

The methods works, and it does what is supposed to do. Nevertheless, when I change the orientation of the device, the activity is recreated, and for any reason that I do not get to understand, the event `afterTextChanged()` is triggered (I do not change its text, or even when reseting changes, cause I am currently just running the app, and switching the orientation), and calls `emptyListView()` and I get the following error:

**ERROR**

Sorry for copying the whole message, but some users were asking for it.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object
>   reference
>           at myFragment.resetListElements(MyFragment.java:930)
>           at Activity$1.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:226)
>           at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:10551)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6278)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6097)
>           at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:122)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6049)
>           at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:5916)
>           at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:19815)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3864)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3864)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3864)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3864)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3864)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3864)
>           at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:19793)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2158)
>           at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1563)
>           at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1518)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1346)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3310)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

I guess the problem is that is calling this method and the `listView` does not exist yet (or the visibility is `GONE).

As you can check, I have added the line `if (m_activity.findViewById(R.id.listView) != null)` to try to avoid call this method, but the view seems to exists. I have also tried using `m_activity.findViewById(R.id.listView).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE` but the error persist.

Any idea about why is this method `afterTextChanged()` triggered? 
**NOTE**

Please, note that I want to have two different layout of my activity when Landscape/Portrait, and therefore I am not adding "orientation" to my activity in the manifest file.

**EDIT**

I have tried removing the watchers in `onDestroy()` but it did not solve it

Comment: Make sure that listView has a value. You check if a view with the ID `listView` exists. But you don't check if the variable `listView` has actually a value.

Comment: Can you share the complete error log, or your project repository?

Comment: From what I see, maybe you did not add a `listView` to the layout landscape or add with another `id`. check it

Comment: The view works in landscape and in portrait individually. The problem is that, when I switch the orientation, that listener is called, and I guess the view is not ready

Comment: the listener is called after `onCreate()`

Comment: Yes it is. I know that when swithing the orientation the activity is re-created but I do not really understand why it automatically triggers the listener (since I do not change the value of the edit text). I also do not see why the first time is able to set the listeners, but when re-creating no

Answer (score 0):

When you change the orientation of the device, your activity is completely recreated. To fix this problem, you need to take care of maintaining the state https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

or add a parameter to the `activity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|uiMode"
```

You can read more here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

Comment: Yes, I know that, but when I added orientation, the layout remains, and I want to have different layouts for Landscape and Portrait.

Comment: the activity is pretty big, and also private. I have tried to emulate the same situation in the question